# libopcodes: get the size of a instruction

Tags: c, assembly, x86, binutils

I have to find out the size of a instruction which I have in memory (actually, I have a small code segment in memory and want to get the size of the first instruction).
It took me some time to find libopcodes and libbfd. I red the headers and tried to come up with a simple solution but it seems like I missunderstood something since the program always crashes:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    disassemble_info *dis = malloc(sizeof(*dis));
    assert(dis != NULL);

    dis->arch = bfd_arch_i386;
    dis->read_memory_func = buffer_read_memory;
    dis->buffer_length = 64;
    dis->buffer = malloc(dis->buffer_length);
    memset(dis->buffer, 0x90, dis->buffer_length);
    disassemble_init_for_target(dis);

    int instr_size = print_insn_i386(0, dis);

    printf("instruction size is %d\n", instr_size);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected result would be an instruction size of 1 (`nop`).

**EDIT**:

sorry guys, I'm a stupid person.

```
memset(dis, 0, sizeof(*dis));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some code in the Linux kernel you can steal. It should work well if copied into a user mode program.

Take a look at arch/x86/lib and arch/x86/tools
There's an opcode map file there, and an awk script that reads it to produce a table in a file named innat.c. There are some other files there that use the table to implement a decoder.

It is sufficient to determine instruction sizes.

This assumes you are ok with GPL, of course.

Comment: Thanks, that will work for x86. What if I want to port it to another architecture, like arm? I didn't find an equivalent there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the disassemble_info data structure requires more initialization than you have provided. From examples I have been studying, the correct way to initialize is to call init_disassemble_info().

See if that helps. Failing that, compile your program with debug info ('-g') and run gdb to diagnose where the crash occurs.

Comment: Added flavour (bfd_target_elf_flavour), mach (bfd_mach_x86_64) and endian (BFD_ENDIAN_LITTLE). Didn't help but I'm not sure what flavour is. I also added init_disassemble_info(dis, NULL, NULL);

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7b1c749 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libopcodes-2.22.90-system.20120924.so
#2  0x0000000000400b5c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe428) at /home/sebastian/prog/libredirect/libredirect/test.c:36

Comment: You may wish to update your program listing to include what you have tried, and also paste / format the gdb stack trace.

Comment: Another item: You're setting buffer and buffer_length, but not buffer_vma. BTW, check out this file: https://github.com/mkfs/opdis/blob/master/opdis/opdis.c ; it leverages libopcodecs. I have been studying it to determine what steps might be missing in your program. This might also be useful to you.